# Debug typescript source file in ionic 2 with visual studio 2015

Tags: debugging, typescript, visual-studio-2015, ionic2, breakpoints

I am in the process on selecting suitable cross-platform development tools for my next mobile project (react-native or ionic 2). I like ionic because of its out-of-the-box use of typescript. I have setup a simple project following basic tutorial and I am able to launch the application via the Ripple emulator.

Now I am asking: is it possible to hit breakpoints in the typescript files?

So far I have been unsuccessful. There is a app.bundle.js (and a corresponding sourcemap) generated after compilation and placed in the .www/build/js folder.
I added this line in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"sourceMap": true
```

When I place a breakpoint in the **app.ts** for example, it is not hit.

How is debugging done? through Chrome browser dev tools or directly from within visual studio? Most of the solutions I have found apply to Visual Studio Code. I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise edition

Thanks in advance for any help, suggestion and direction

Answer (score 0):

You can set breakpoints in .ts files and debug using Chrome remote debugging on an android device. Just issue `ionic run android` to build and deploy on the real android device, open Chrome and use chrome://inspect to view the sources and set breakpoints.

Note that you may need to configure to add the source maps inline - see [Ionic 2: Application running on the android device can't be debugged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41413082/ionic-2-application-running-on-the-android-device-cant-be-debugged/41414355#41414355)