# Ionic 2: Application running on the android device can't be debugged

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2

Steps to reproduce:
 1. Created new project from
    https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-super
 2. run `ionic run android``
 3. use chrome://inspect to debug

There is no ts  and debug is not working - see attached
[image]

Here is what I'm using:
Cordova CLI: 6.4.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.48
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0
ios-sim version: 5.0.13
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.2
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find out what was causing the problem and how to solve it. The problem was that when you're remote debugging on an android device, Chrome debugger cannot access the source map file on the device. The solution/fix is to include the source map inline. To do this I:

added the below to package.json in the root project directory

```
"config": {
"ionic_bundler": "webpack",
"ionic_source_map_type": "#inline-source-map"
},
```

This is to make the webpack to add source maps inline
changed tsconfig.js line

```
"sourceMap": true,
```

to

```
"sourceMap": false
```

This is to disable typescript to create source map file since this is done by webpack.

After this change everything seems to be working fine

Comment: The custom `ionic_source_map_type` might lead to issues during prod builds. As a workaround, you can restrict this config to dev builds by first defining a [custom webpack config file](https://artyomsokolov.com/how-to-use-different-environment-variables-for-production-and-development-with-ionic-3/), then adjsting the config with `useDefaultConfig.dev.devtool = '#inline-source-map'` (insert this line into the linked example *webpack.config.js*).